# Json_encode generate null value while try to connect two database

Tags: mysql, json

I have use utf8_unicode_ci for my collation for all the field of my two database.For english language and number is was fine but for thai language it not showed.It show just null.I try to do many way but still.But if i remove $dbh2 it is perfectly work but i need both

```
<?php    
$timezone = "Asia/Bangkok";  
if(function_exists('date_default_timezone_set')) date_default_timezone_set($timezone);

$dbh1 = mysql_connect('localhost','user1','pass1', true);
$dbh2 = mysql_connect('localhost','user2','pass2', true);

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8");
mysql_select_db('DB1', $dbh1); 
mysql_select_db('DB2', $dbh2);

$name=$_GET['name'];
$data=array();

$search=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `uname` = '".$name."'",$dbh2);


    while($a=mysql_fetch_assoc($search))
    {
        $data[]=$a['total_point'];
    }  

    $find=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `item` order by `item_id` DESC",$dbh1);
     while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($find))
     {
          $data[]=$r;
      }


     echo json_encode($data);
```

?>

and output is this

```
    [ "0",
        {
            "item_id": "10",
            "item_band": "Gift Card",
            "item_pic": "http://www.puncorp.com/Applications/GuruLotto/Lotto/card_04.png",
            "item_title": "Gift Card",
            "item_detail": null,
            "item_introduction": null,
            "item_point": "30000",
            "item_point_bg": "0",
            "item_available": "97",
            "item_rule": null,
            "item_expired": "30/12/2556",
            "item_confirm_deal": null,
            "item_confirm_use": null,
            "item_image_total": "10",
            "item_image1": "http://www.puncorp.com/Applications/GuruLotto/Lotto/card_04.png", 
            "status": "6"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Your json starts with a rogue `{`. Remove that and it should parse. You can use a tool as [jslint](http://jsonlint.com/) to verify the validity of your json.

Comment: Okay, my initial answer doesn't seem to be your question. I am confused about what your actual question is. `json_encode` doesn't return NULL. It will either return a string or false on failure. `json_encode` works with UTF-8 encoded data, so that means something else is converting your utf-8 encoded data to ASCII or some other encoding that doesn't have those characters. Try using [mysql_set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php) for your encoding instead, so that both sides are aware you want to work with utf-8.

Comment: yep it return some of value in null

Comment: I bet that `var_dump( $data[0]['item_detail'] )` would be NULL if you echoed it before the json_encode.

Comment: var_dump( $data[0]['item_detail'] ) it is null it s shown  string(1) "0" but i try to echo $r inside while loop it shown me Chinese language.